# How do I organise my CloudFront Behaviors to serve the correct SPA app when using separate buckets for a path based app

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge, cloudfront-functions

I have a single distribution which serves 2 SPAs, the main app works but the path based app is not able to load the required assets when the index.html page loads.

Here is an example of the setup:

[image: CloudFront Example]

In summary:

- 1 x Distribution with OAC enabled
- 5 x behaviors, including the default(*)
- 2 x origin response Lambda@Edge functions that check for 403 and 404 responses
- 2 x S3 origins pointing to
- 2 x S3 buckets with OAC enabled

The origin response functions handle redirecting when the bucket returns a 403. The only difference is the function for the *bar* behaviors uses the */bar/* prefix for its re-routing.

The main app loads fine and all the assets load, but when I try and load the */bar* route it will load the */bar/index.html* but then all the subsequent */bar/runtime.js* files are not loading. The requests seem to be skipping the first 3 behaviors and triggering the default behavior and origin response function which then returns the main apps index content instead of the correct js file.

I originally had the following behavior paths:

- /bar/index.html
- /bar
- index.html
- *

and added the */bar/** path to see if this was required but it made no difference.

I seem unable to resolve this myself and would like to see if there is a problem with my setup or whether there is another issue that I am unaware of.

Comment: Interestingly, if I only run 1 origin response function for all the Behaviors and have that function check for the */bar/* path prefix, it serves the content correctly, What I still don't understand is why the Behaviors don't seem to trigger the correct function when they are assigned different origin response functions.